# How to detect if there is little to no change in time series data?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to filter some columns in dataframe where there is little to no change in the data throughout, an example plot of one of the columns is shown below:

[image]

What I'm doing currently is quite simple and is probably very inefficient.

```py
from collections import Counter

n = data2.shape[0]

for col in data2.columns:
    most_freq = Counter(data2[col]).most_common(1)[0][1]
    print(col, most_freq/n)
```

It's output:

```
m0 0.25192519251925194
m1 0.5808580858085809
m2 0.09790979097909791
m3 0.0033003300330033004
m4 0.9713971397139713
m5 1.0
m6 1.0
m7 1.0
m8 1.0
m9 0.9713971397139713
m10 1.0
m11 1.0
```

As you can see, I'd like to filter out the columns (like m5, m6 etc) which have high volume of constant non-changing values. Is there a better, perhaps some *statistical* way to do it? I've looked at a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043399/how-to-detect-if-change-in-time-series-data-is-no-longer-significant) but it didn't help much.

Update:

Based on @Kosmo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70953190/8421501), this seemed to work well for me. At least, it helped me remove the obvious ones with flat lines.

```
data2 = data2.loc[:, (round(data2.var()) > 0)]
```

Comment: You can use a linear regression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feature selection via [variance threshold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.VarianceThreshold.html#sklearn.feature_selection.VarianceThreshold).

Variance is a great statistic to use if you want information on the variability

Edit:
I think a cleaner solution would be to simply use `DataFrame.var()` and filter based on that.