# Test to check if my time series is constant for a long period of time

Tags: python, time-series

How can I measure, if my time series is not changing with time , that is the value is constant for a very long period of time(not looking for stationarity test)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly would fit your needs but here are some things I can think of are -

1. Just Plot it if it's small enough to identify regions of constant value
2. Write a small piece of code which finds subarrays with same value being repeated for a certain number of times if you want the value to be absolutely constant, alternatively you can add a tolerance so that values within a +- range are accepted

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9117089/13858953) might interest you